# Get Twitter userId using twitter api

Tags: twitter

I can able to get All the users details by using

https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json

But i want to get only ID by using api

How to obtain that.

I dont want to extract from the total credentials.

I want like facebook URL

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id

It returns only ID.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible yet, you have to extract from total credential.

Answer (score 1):

The closest Twitter comes to something like this is the `GET friends/ids` endpoint, which will return a list of friend IDs for a given Twitter user.

Details here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/ids

Comment: This seems to be about only the authorized user.